# How to include "," only between items?

Tags: c#, string

Okay i have the code here:

```
string value = "";
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    value += "," + item.ToString();
}
textBox3.Text = value;
```

I only want the `","` after the first word like this
`"Test, Test, Test"`
Instead it does this
`",Test,Test,Test"`

Comment: Use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx) - none of that Java-style code junk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you find that the other answer is not compilable, the answer is here

```
textBox3.Text = String.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<string>());
```

In case you want to do it the classical way

```
string value = "";
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    value += item.ToString() + ",";
}
textBox3.Text = value.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: Why would the other answer not compile? Also, `ToString()` works even if the ListBox is not populated with strings! (Let's say we added an int32 there)

Comment: LINQ was not always there

Comment: @SepehrFarshid `listBox1.Items` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. So you can't use `Select` unless you `Cast` it like in this answer.  Why don't you try it?

Comment: Oh god! My bad, fixed.

Comment: You can also use the `OfType<T>` method to avoid invalid casts.

Comment: Which will then ignore all my int32s :(

Answer (score 7):

Use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Concatenates the elements of a specified array or the members of a collection, using the specified separator between each element or member.

Example:

```
textBox3.Text = String.Join(", ", listBox1.Items.Cast<object>());
```

(thanks to @EZI and @Selman22 for pointing out issues in code)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, it is. But the `String` class is not from LINQ.

Comment: i was taking about the ``Select``

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 basic things you can do here if you want to stick with the original code as much as possible----- 
1)
    `string value = "";
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        value += "," + item.ToString();
    }
    value.Remove(0,1);    //removes the 1st character, which is the offending ","
    textBox3.Text = value;`

2)
    `string value = "";
    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
    {
        value += item.ToString() + ",";    //swaps original order of the item and ","
    }
    value.Remove(value.length - 1,1);    //removes last character, which will be a ","
    textBox3.Text = value;`

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the for loop, use

```
value = value.substring(1);
```

to just erase the first character.